# Datepicker in Bootstrap is not popping up automatically

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

When I am clicking on the input field it only gets focus, but it doesn't show the datepicker unless I go at the extreme right corner of the field and click on the 'caret icon'. As this field attains focus, it should automatically popup the datepicker.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <h4>FROM DATE: </h4><input type="date" id="fd" name="fdate" class="form-    `        control" placeholder="Enter date" required> </input> 
</div>
```

I have included the `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap.js` files.

Any ideas?

Comment: share your JavaScript code.

Comment: You need Bootstrap 2.0.4+ and jQuery 1.7.1+ And, do you have configured the date-picker? example: `$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    startDate: '-3d'
})` https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: do we need to add any other js file specifically of datepicker even if we have included bootstrap.css  and bootstrap.js ??